# FourSquare API: {"error":"unsupported_grant_type"}

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, foursquare

I am trying to connect the following app to FourSquare:

http://almontas.github.io/FourSquareJax/

However I keep on getting this error message:

```
{"error":"unsupported_grant_type"}
```

Any ideas as to what can be contributing to this error?  See my code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var foursquareApi = {
                clientId: "4B4T220TQF43NIUKJAQI1DNASEOI12NBTTUNZ5YOETDDQORF",
                clientSecret: "YDBCTHJECBNMQVFWRC1GU5RFGGPHRY4Y1VGHSVD4PLMGRKNB",
                redirectUrl : "http://almontas.github.io/FourSquareJax/"
            }



if (access_token == null) {       
    $('.dashboardProfile').hide();   
    $('.dashboardInfo').hide(); 
    $('.dashboardConnect').show();   
    $('.connect').click(function() {   
        var url = "https://foursquare.com/oauth2/access_token";
        url += "?client_id="+foursquareApi.clientId;
        url += "&response_type=token";
        url += "&redirect_uri="+foursquareApi.redirectUrl;
        window.location = url;
    });
}
else {
    $('.dashboardProfile').show();   
    $('.dashboardInfo').show();
    $('.dashboardConnect').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL was wrong:

1)  This is what I have:  "https://foursquare.com/oauth2/access_token";

2) This is what it should be: "https://foursquare.com/oauth2/**authenticate"**;